# What is the response time from the USPTO when reviving a non-provisional application "after" two years that was unintentionally abandoned?

Tags: unintentional, reviving

What is the response time from the USPTO when reviving a non-provisional application "after" two years that was unintentionally abandoned? Do I need to add detailed information on why it was unintentionally abandoned? If so, who is this information submitted to (petitions)?

Note: The application issue fee was paid - abandoned because the Inventor's Oath was filed after the Issuance fee was paid - the attorney never notified us and then he stopped practicing law recently; we just discovered this information.

Thank you in advance.

JB